# Create Relational Tables from Nested Hash in Ruby

Tags: ruby, hash, sequel

I am trying to create tables using Ruby Sequel based on a nested hash.

There are dozens of hashes containing dozens of arrays and arrays of hashs, but let's say I have the following nested hash;

```
{name:'Bob', age: 40, hobbies: [{title: 'breakdancing', skill: 10}, {title: 'yodeling', skill: 7}], favorite_foods: ["Broccoli", "Sardines"]}
```

What is the cleanest way to create the relational tables programatically; let's say 'Users', 'Hobbies', and 'Foods' using the hash? Would I then have to go in and set the field types?

I'm just learning Ruby, but it would seem counterproductive manually creating fields and then manually mapping and assigning values from a perfectly good hash.

Comment: This question is tagged ruby-on-rails, so I have to assume you're using Rails. If you are new to Ruby and Rails I would suggest using the default ORM, Active Record, with Rails. ActiveRecord manages relational database schemas using "migrations".  See the [Active Record Migrations Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html).

Comment: It's not Ruby on Rails, but I'll figure out how to untag the question. I am actually just using a ruby prompt with a single .rb file. I know about migrations, and manually adding fields. I would just like to do something like set the DB to the hash. Is there ot a params: function which does something like this?

Answer (score 0):

Per the [Sequel documentation](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/files/doc/schema_modification_rdoc.html) you can use "create_table ... for adding new tables to the database".

```
create_table(:artists) do
  primary_key :id
  String :name
end
```

So, yes - you would need to do that once for each of the nested arrays or hashes you want to be separate tables. You may want to first go through the exercise of turning those hashes into POROs (Plain Old Ruby Objects) as you could then leverage those classes to create the tables.

Answer (score 0):

The answer lies in the nested attributes plugin. More info can be obtained below. Yes, this does not magically create the tables, but will allow writing in one fell swoop.

http://www.nerdgem.com/tutorials/3-adding-nested-attributes-to-models

```
require 'sequel'

DB = Sequel.sqlite('user_test.db')

#DB.create_table(:users) do
#  primary_key :user_id
#  String :name
#end
#
#DB.create_table(:skills) do
#  primary_key :skill_id
#  Integer :user_id
#  String :desc
#  Integer :level
#end

#Models;
class User < Sequel::Model
  one_to_many :skills

  self.plugin :instance_hooks
  self.plugin :nested_attributes
end

class Skill < Sequel::Model
  many_to_one :user
end


User.nested_attributes :skills

#Ruby Hash;
user_info = {:name => "Mike", :skills_attributes => [{:desc => "Curling", :level => 3}, {:desc => "Sorcery", :level => 4}]}

p record = User.create(user_info)
```